# How to have a model with single covariate?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, covariance

I am working on a data with 14 columns and I must have ccarduse as the response and prodebt as the single covariate. How am I suppose to do this correctly?
This is what it came to my mind:

```
mod1<-multinom(ccarduse~prodebt, debt)
# weights:  9 (4 variable)
initial  value 429.557405 
final  value 386.378125 
converged
```

also I was planning on creating a graph to predicted probabilities of  each credit card against prodebt scores.
I used the following code but unfortunately it doesn't give me a graph nor an error could you please guide?

```
    preds=predict(mod1,data.frame(debt=prodebt),type="probs")
    plot(debt, preds[,1],ylim=c(.15,.6),xlab="credit card",ylab="Probabilities of Party identification")
Error in plot.default(...) : 
  formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Comment: What exactly is the question ?

Comment: @Firebug how to write a multinominal model having prodebt as single covariant and ccarduse as response?

Comment: 1. Your code looks correct to me (I assume "debt" is the name of your dataframe in r). 2. Did you check your plot by running just the command"plot" (without quotes) after running the graphing code? (also you have extra + marks on each row but I assume they came from copy paste - they would produce an error).

Comment: @Sointu I did try to graph it by plot it gave me Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'.

Comment: @Sointu I edited the question could you please check predicted plot

Comment: Sorry, when you said you didn't get any error I though maybe you didn't check it at all. And sorry again, I'm not sure about that error (I use ggplot and rarely the base r plot), but I think there's something wrong about the data.frame command inside predict.

Comment: @Sointu it's okay if I use ggplot. it's the data debt from faraway package could you please help me with the plot

Comment: No sorry, I don't understand the error as I rarely use the base plot :(

Answer (score 1):

The predictions from your model give predictions of multiple different (but related) quantities. In particular, you get a predicted probability for each category in `ccarduse`, since the model is multinomial.

If you want to plot these predicted probabilities, you have to plot your `prodebt` against each column of your predictions. You can display this in multiple plots or with the values on top of either; it's your choice.

Comment: The statistical insight here is that the multinomial logistic regression gives multiple predicted probabilities (one per category), rather than just one like you get out of a linear regression. Whatever plotting functions you run downstream from the predictions either needs to know how to interpret the prediction output or have the predictions wrestled into a format that the functions understand.